# How to export all subscribers from data extension WITH the date of the most recent email they opened

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, data, data-export

How to export all subscribers from data extension WITH the date of the most recent email they opened?

Is there a SQL query that could be used to create this type of Data Extension for export, so that we can plan how to re-engage previously suppressed users?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! Please add information on what you already tried and where you are stuck. For further info on how to ask good questions, check out the [How to ask-section](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have tried creating a MEASURE for today minus 5 months, 4 months, 3 months and so on. But MEASUREs only go back up to 6 months, and I am being asked to supply a full breakdown going back 1 year.  Where that will show me a list of users email and the date of the most recent email they opened.

Comment: I am stuck in that nothing I have tried is working. Measures only go back up to 6 months, and I need to go back further (1 year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Measures, Queries also go back up to 6 months only. The only option left is Data Extract. There also you'll have to do 4 quarterly extract to sum up the full year. Once you have to it, you'll have to do all the data crunching in excel sheets

You can ask Salesforce to create a custom Data View/ Report for you. There is no out of the box way to meet this requirement